# Google Sheets transpose multiple columns with multiple data into Details in Rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of responses from a google form (Columns A to G).
I need to transform the data into details, to be like the data shown in column K to O.

[image]

In Sheet2!G2 , I have put the formula that still needs to split the column K, then transpose it to vertical with the "Record" refers to Column J.

The spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13yQa2HH5D-6gJWc9NPNUEdQNkhxicfZkc7LWJC5kUME/edit#gid=457678832

Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

In Cell A18 (sheet2) I entered

```
={"Date","Grade","Subject", "Record"; query(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(datevalue(Data!C2:C)&"|"&Data!D2:D&"|"&Data!B2:B&"|"&SPLIT(Data!E2:E,", ")), "|")), "Where Col4 <>''")}
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: Thank you for responding..

I still need 1 more column in column E to be added in every record of row.
as you can see in the sheet Data in column N. 
The "Record" refer to the header of the data source (E1:G1).

Comment: I have improved the formula in Cell G2 (Sheet2). 
Still need to split & transpose the Column K to vertical with the "Record" refers to Column J.

Really appreciate if you can help